# fputcsv Notice: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, foreach, fopen, fputcsv

I have a simple PHP code to save JSON to CSV , but I have an error, this the code:

```
<?php
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('https://url');

$out = fopen('C:\xampp\htdocs\tkp_product\tkp2.csv', 'w');
foreach(json_decode($inputJSON, true)["data"] as $key => $value) {
  fputcsv($out, $value);
}
fclose($out);

?>
```

This for error for `fputcsv($out, $value);`

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\tkp.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\tkp.php on line 6

I'm running this script using XAMPP in Win 10 with PHP7 installed. What should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are the line numbers the same here as in tkp.php? Which line is line 6?

Comment: Wait I'm editing a question

Comment: CSV is a flat format, so `fputcsv`'s second argument is supposed to be a flat array. Your `$value` is an array that contains other arrays. PHP converts them to strings (so that they can be written out as a single CSV field) and emits a notice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for type of value

```
foreach(json_decode($inputJSON, true)["data"] as $key => $value) {
 if(!is_array($value)) fputcsv($out, $value);
}
```

But note it seems that `file_get_contents('https://url');` return a nested arrays, this will get just the first level

Comment: fputcsv Not working..  This a sample JSON I'm using https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7b8fe84d482cd7f7b95a13187ae1cac7

Comment: It seems that your json has more than one level, How can you want save it as CSV ? CSV is line by line structure and json is hierarchy structure so how json converted to csv